# Remove subarray using pointer arithmetic

Tags: arrays, c, pointers, pointer-arithmetic

I need to make a function for removing subarray using pointer arithmetic in C. Function should return number of removed elements. Auxiliary arrays are not allowed.

```
#include <stdio.h>
int remove_subarray(int * first_start, int * first_end,const int * second_start,const int * second_end) {
  int size_of_second = second_end-second_start;
  int *subarray_start, *last = first_end - 1;
  const int *pok = second_start,*second_start_copy = second_start;
  int number_of_the_same = 0;
  while (first_start != first_end) {
    if ( * first_start == * second_start) {
      if (number_of_the_same == 0)
       subarray_start = first_start;
      first_start++;
      second_start++;
      number_of_the_same++;
      if (number_of_the_same == size_of_second) {
        first_start = subarray_start;
        while (1) {
          if ( *first_start == *last)
            break;
          subarray_start = first_start;
          subarray_start += size_of_second;
          *first_start = *subarray_start;
          first_start++;
        }
        break;
      }
    } else {
      number_of_the_same = 0;
      first_start++;
      second_start = second_start_copy;
    }
  }
  return size_of_second;
}
int main() {
  // This gives correct result
  int niz1[14] = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, -1},i;
  int niz2[4] = {2, 3, 4, 5};
  int k1 = remove_subarray(niz1, niz1 + 14, niz2, niz2 + 4);
  for (i = 0; i < 14 - k1; ++i)
    printf("%i ", niz1[i]);
  printf("\n");
  // This gives wrong result
  int niz3[10] = {1, 1, 2, 3, 5, 6, 1, 2, 4, 10};
  int niz4[3] = {1, 2, 3};
  int k2 = remove_subarray(niz3, niz3 + 10, niz4, niz4 + 3);
  for (i = 0; i < 10 - k2; i++) printf("%d ", niz3[i]);
  return 0;
}
```

My algorithm is the following:

- if elements match, save position to pointer *start*
- if number_of_the_same (elements) is equal to number of elements in second array (n) that means subarray is found
- if subarray is found, I set all elements to be equal to the elements that are n positions forward them

In the main function I tried with two set of arrays (*niz1 and niz2*) and for the first set it worked correct. However it didn't work correct for second set of arrays (*niz3 and niz4*).

Could you help me to fix my code?

Comment: What is different between the two sets of arrays, the ones that worked and those that did no?  Did initial conditions change between the two runs?  variables all re-initialized properly?

Comment: @ryyker Both sets are in the `main()` function.

Comment: FYI, you don't need the loop to set `n`, you can just use `n = q2 - q1;`

Comment: It would really help if you used better variable names. There are so many short pointer names that it's difficult to keep track of which are which.

Comment: I suspect the reason for the failure is that the subarray begins with `1` and there are `1` in the main array that don't match. But I find it too difficult to follow the logic because of the variable names.

Comment: @Barmar p1 - start of array1, p2 - end of array1, q1 - start of array2, q2 - end of array2, start = position where the same elements start, last - last element of array1, p - start of array2 (it doesn't change)

Comment: I can figure it out if I try, but it's still hard to keep them in mind when reading the loop.

Comment: At the point that `n==4` here:

    `start += n;`

`start` is over array bounds when working on the arrays `niz1` & `niz2` in the code you are showing.  So, if everything appeared to work with these two arrays as you state, either the code you are showing is modified from what is actually used, or there is some kind of undefined behavior at work.  (i.e. it does not make it beyond this call:  `int k1 = remove_subarray(niz1, niz1 + 14, niz2, niz2 + 4);` .)

Comment: I changed names of variables to make it more clear

Comment: You'll have to interpret my last comment according to your previous naming convention, but there is a problem at that point that is contributing to the problem

Comment: has anyone figured out what is the problem here?

Comment: problem is that when, after finding the first element of the sub_array, if the search fails you **can not update** the pointer for the array. The element pointed at can be again the first one of the sub_array, like the doubled `1`at your second set. I will show an example

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The provided code is very hard to read and so is also hard to test. At least for me. May be the author could have used more meaningful names.

I think that the bug in the original code is that, after finding the first number of the sub_array, if the search fails the program **must not** advance the pointer of the array, because the current value pointed to can be the real start of the sequence and the previous just a false positive. See the pair `1,1` in the second supplied set

I will let an example with 2 options that may help.

> A TL;DR section is now at the end with a shorter example

#### The method in the example

The idea is that

- you have an array and if it contains a certain sub_array you need to do something with the sub_array. Like a *predicate function* in other languages.
- the arguments are open-ended segments like the iterators in `C++ STL`: first argument points to first element, second argument points past the end of the array
- two functions are in the code

  - `remove_subarray()` that moves the entire sub_array to the end of the array
  - `mark_subarray()` that replaces all sub_array values by `INT_MAX`

### Making things easier: a few helper functions

### `int  show_array(const int*, const int*, const char*);`

This function has 5 lines: just write down the array with an optional title like here

```
    char buffer[80] = {0};
    sprintf(buffer, "%d elements moved. Resulting array:", res);
    show_array(array, array + sz_arr, buffer);
```

or here

```
    show_array(array, array + sz_arr, "Base array:");
```

sample output:

```
3 elements moved. Resulting array:    [  1  2  4  10  5  6  1  1  2  3  ]
```

or

```
              Base array:    [  1  1  2  3  5  6  1  2  4  10  ]
```

#### `int* find_sub_array(const int*, const int*, const int*, const int*);`

returns `NULL` if the sub_array is not found in the array, or the address of the sub_array.

This type of things are easily expressed by a *FSM*, a state machine. Here we need a minimalist set of 2 states:

- one before find the possible start of a sub_array
- one to search for the rest of the sub_array

A possible implementation

```
int* find_sub_array(
    const int* arr_start, const int* arr_end,
    const int* sa_start, const int* sa_end)
{  
    char st    = 0;
    int* pA    = (int*)arr_start;
    int* pSA   = (int*)sa_start;
    int* sa_ix = 0;  // address of the sub_array in array
    while (1)
    {
        switch (st)
        {
            case 0:
                if (*pA == *pSA)
                {
                    st    = 1;
                    sa_ix = pA;         // found 1st
                    pSA += 1, pA += 1;  // both pointers up
                    break;
                }
                pA += 1;  // array pointer only
                break;
            case 1:
            default:
            {
                if (*pA != *pSA)
                {
                    pSA = (int*)sa_start;  // reset
                    st  = 0;               // back to search
                    break;
                }
                else
                    pSA += 1, pA += 1;  // both goup
                if (pSA == sa_end) return sa_ix;
                break;
            }
        };  // end switch()
        if (pA >= arr_end) return NULL;
    }
    return NULL;
}
```

#### `remove_subarray()`

Using these functions one can write `remove_subarray()` in a compact way

```
int remove_subarray(
    int* first_start, int* first_end,
    const int* second_start, const int* second_end)
{
    int* pos = find_sub_array(
        first_start, first_end, second_start, second_end);
    if (pos == NULL) return 0;
    int sz_sub_arr = (int)(second_end - second_start);
    for (int ix = 0; ix < sz_sub_arr; ix += 1)
        *pos++ = INT_MAX;  // set all elements to INT_MAX
    return sz_sub_arr;
}
```

#### Testing multiple versions

The version above changes sub_array values. Another one in the example code moves the sub_array to the end. It is just an example anyway.

```
void test_with(
    int array[], int, int sub_arr[], int sz_sub_arr,
    int (*)(int*, int*, const int*, const int*));
```

This one accepts the name of the function to apply to the parameters, like a `for_each()` in *C++* or *java*. It is used in the example like this:

```
    printf("\nUsing 1st provided set\n");
    int niz3[10] = {1, 1, 2, 3, 5, 6, 1, 2, 4, 10};
    int niz4[3]  = {1, 2, 3};
    test_with(niz3, 10, niz4, 3, remove_subarray);

    int niz1[14] = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7,
                    0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, -1};
    int niz2[4]  = {2, 3, 4, 5};
    printf( "\
\nUsing 2nd provided set + function to set sub_array elements to "
        "INT_MAX\n\n");
    test_with(
        niz1, sizeof(niz1) / sizeof(niz1[0]), niz2,
        sizeof(niz2) / sizeof(niz2[0]), mark_subarray);
```

#### output for the example code

```
total of 4 basic tests

Test 1 of 4:
              Base array:    [  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9  10  11  12  13  14  15  16  ]
               Sub_array:    [  1  2  3  ]
3 elements moved. Resulting array:    [  14  15  16  4  5  6  7  8  9  10  11  12  13  1  2  3  ]

Test 2 of 4:
              Base array:    [  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9  10  11  12  13  14  15  16  ]
               Sub_array:    [  1  2  4  ]
0 elements moved. Resulting array:    [  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9  10  11  12  13  14  15  16  ]

Test 3 of 4:
              Base array:    [  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9  10  11  12  13  14  15  16  ]
               Sub_array:    [  14  15  16  ]
[nothing to move: subarray found already at the end]
0 elements moved. Resulting array:    [  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9  10  11  12  13  14  15  16  ]

Test 4 of 4:
              Base array:    [  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9  10  11  12  13  14  15  16  ]
               Sub_array:    [  13  14  15  ]
3 elements moved. Resulting array:    [  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9  10  11  12  16  13  14  15  ]

Using 1st provided set
              Base array:    [  1  1  2  3  5  6  1  2  4  10  ]
               Sub_array:    [  1  2  3  ]
3 elements moved. Resulting array:    [  1  2  4  10  5  6  1  1  2  3  ]

Using 2nd provided set + function to set sub_array elements to INT_MAX

              Base array:    [  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  0  1  2  3  4  5  -1  ]
               Sub_array:    [  2  3  4  5  ]
4 elements moved. Resulting array:    [  1  2147483647  2147483647  2147483647  2147483647  6  7  0  1  2  3  4  5  -1  ]
```

#### Example code

```
#include <limits.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int* find_sub_array(
    const int*, const int*, const int*, const int*);
int  mark_subarray(int*, int*, const int*, const int*);
int  remove_subarray(int*, int*, const int*, const int*);
int  set_array(int*, size_t);
int  shift_array(int*, int*, int);
int  show_array(const int*, const int*, const char*);
void test_with(
    int array[], int, int sub_arr[], int sz_sub_arr,
    int (*)(int*, int*, const int*, const int*));

int main(void)
{
    int array[16]    = {0};
    int sz_arr       = sizeof(array) / sizeof(array[0]);
    int sub_arr[][3] = {
        {1, 2, 3}, {1, 2, 4}, {14, 15, 16}, {13, 14, 15}};
    const int sz_sub_arr =
        sizeof(sub_arr[0]) / sizeof(sub_arr[0][0]);
    const n_of_tests = sizeof(sub_arr) / sizeof(sub_arr[0]);

    printf("total of %d basic tests\n", n_of_tests);

    for (int tst = 0; tst < n_of_tests; tst += 1)
    {
        printf("\nTest %d of %d:\n", 1 + tst, n_of_tests);
        set_array(array, sz_arr);
        test_with(
            array, sz_arr, sub_arr[tst], sz_sub_arr,
            remove_subarray);
    }

    printf("\nUsing 1st provided set\n");
    int niz3[10] = {1, 1, 2, 3, 5, 6, 1, 2, 4, 10};
    int niz4[3]  = {1, 2, 3};
    test_with(niz3, 10, niz4, 3, remove_subarray);

    int niz1[14] = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7,
                    0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, -1};
    int niz2[4]  = {2, 3, 4, 5};
    printf(
        "\
\nUsing 2nd provided set + function to set sub_array elements to "
        "INT_MAX\n\n");
    test_with(
        niz1, sizeof(niz1) / sizeof(niz1[0]), niz2,
        sizeof(niz2) / sizeof(niz2[0]), mark_subarray);

    return 0;
}

int* find_sub_array(
    const int* arr_start, const int* arr_end,
    const int* sa_start, const int* sa_end)
{
    char st    = 0;
    int* pA    = (int*)arr_start;
    int* pSA   = (int*)sa_start;
    int* sa_ix = 0;  // address of the sub_array in array
    while (1)
    {
        switch (st)
        {
            case 0:
                if (*pA == *pSA)
                {
                    st    = 1;
                    sa_ix = pA;         // found 1st
                    pSA += 1, pA += 1;  // both pointers up
                    break;
                }
                pA += 1;  // array pointer only
                break;
            case 1:
            default:
            {
                if (*pA != *pSA)
                {
                    pSA = (int*)sa_start;  // reset
                    st  = 0;               // back to search
                    break;
                }
                else
                    pSA += 1, pA += 1;  // both goup
                if (pSA == sa_end) return sa_ix;
                break;
            }
        };  // end switch()
        if (pA >= arr_end) return NULL;
    }
    return NULL;
}

int mark_subarray(
    int* first_start, int* first_end,
    const int* second_start, const int* second_end)
{
    int* pos = find_sub_array(
        first_start, first_end, second_start, second_end);
    if (pos == NULL) return 0;
    int sz_sub_arr = (int)(second_end - second_start);
    for (int ix = 0; ix < sz_sub_arr; ix += 1)
        *pos++ = INT_MAX;  // set all elements to INT_MAX
    return sz_sub_arr;
}

int remove_subarray(
    int* first_start, int* first_end,
    const int* second_start, const int* second_end)
{
    int* pos = find_sub_array(
        first_start, first_end, second_start, second_end);
    if (pos == NULL) return 0;
    int sz_sub_arr = (int)(second_end - second_start);
    if ((first_end - pos - sz_sub_arr) == 0)
    {  // sub_array found but already at the end
        fprintf(
            stderr,
            "[nothing to move: subarray found already at "
            "the end]\n");
        return 0;
    }
    return shift_array(pos, first_end - 1, sz_sub_arr);
}

int set_array(int* v, size_t len)
{  // set the array from 1 to len
    for (int i = 0; i < len; v[i] = 1 + i, i += 1)
        ;
    return 0;
};

int shift_array(int* src, int* last, int len)
{  // shift sub_array to the end od the array
    int* l = src + len - 1;
    int* r = last;
    for (int x = 0; x < len; x += 1, --r, --l)
    {
        int temp = *r;
        *r       = *l;
        *l       = temp;
    }
    return (int)len;
}

int show_array(
    const int* vct, const int* past_end, const char* msg)
{
    if (msg != NULL) printf("%25s", msg);
    printf("    [");
    for (const int* p = vct; p != past_end; p += 1)
        printf("  %d", *p);
    printf("  ]\n");
    return 0;
}

void test_with(
    int array[], int sz_arr, int sub_arr[], int sz_sub_arr,
    int (*f)(int*, int*, const int*, const int*))
{
    show_array(array, array + sz_arr, "Base array:");
    show_array(
        sub_arr, sub_arr + sz_sub_arr, " Sub_array:");

    int res = (*f)(
        array, array + sz_arr, sub_arr,
        sub_arr + sz_sub_arr);

    char buffer[80] = {0};
    sprintf(
        buffer, "%d elements moved. Resulting array:", res);
    show_array(array, array + sz_arr, buffer);
    return;
}
```

### TL;DR

The second example has just code for the original test cases and `find_array()`

#### Example 2

```
#include <limits.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int* find_sub_array(
    const int*, const int*, const int*, const int*);
int  remove_subarray(int*, int*, const int*, const int*);
int  show_array(const int*, const int*, const char*);

int main(void)
{
    int niz1[14] = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7,
                    0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, -1};
    int niz2[4]  = {2, 3, 4, 5};
    printf("\nUsing 1st provided set\n");
    show_array(
        niz1, niz1 + sizeof(niz1) / sizeof(niz1[0]),
        "Base array:");
    show_array(
        niz2, niz2 + sizeof(niz2) / sizeof(niz2[0]),
        " Sub_array:");

    int res = remove_subarray(
        niz1, niz1 + sizeof(niz1) / sizeof(niz1[0]), 
        niz2, niz2 + sizeof(niz2) / sizeof(niz2[0]));

    char buffer[80] = {0};
    sprintf(
        buffer, "%d elements moved. Resulting array:", res);
    show_array(
        niz1, niz1 + sizeof(niz1) / sizeof(niz1[0]),
        "Resulting array:");

    printf("\nUsing 2nd provided set\n");
    int niz3[10] = {1, 1, 2, 3, 5, 6, 1, 2, 4, 10};
    int niz4[3]  = {1, 2, 3};
    show_array(niz3,niz3 + sizeof(niz3) / sizeof(niz3[0]),
        "Base array:");
    show_array(
        niz4,niz4 + sizeof(niz4) / sizeof(niz4[0]),
        " Sub_array:");

    res = remove_subarray(
       niz3,niz3 + sizeof(niz3) / sizeof(niz3[0]),
        niz4,niz4 + sizeof(niz4) / sizeof(niz4[0]));

    sprintf(
        buffer, "%d elements moved. Resulting array:", res);
    show_array(
        niz3, niz3 + sizeof(niz3) / sizeof(niz3[0]),
        "Resulting array:");

    return 0;
}

int* find_sub_array(
    const int* arr_start, const int* arr_end,
    const int* sa_start, const int* sa_end)
{
    char st    = 0;
    int* pA    = (int*)arr_start;
    int* pSA   = (int*)sa_start;
    int* sa_ix = 0;  // address of the sub_array in array
    while (1)
    {
        switch (st)
        {
            case 0:
                if (*pA == *pSA)
                {
                    st    = 1;
                    sa_ix = pA;         // found 1st
                    pSA += 1, pA += 1;  // both pointers up
                    break;
                }
                pA += 1;  // array pointer only
                break;
            case 1:
            default:
            {
                if (*pA != *pSA)
                {
                    pSA = (int*)sa_start;  // reset
                    st  = 0;               // back to search
                    break;
                }
                else
                    pSA += 1, pA += 1;  // both goup
                if (pSA == sa_end) return sa_ix;
                break;
            }
        };  // end switch()
        if (pA >= arr_end) return NULL;
    }
    return NULL;
}

int remove_subarray(
    int* first_start, int* first_end,
    const int* second_start, const int* second_end)
{
    int* pos = find_sub_array(
        first_start, first_end, second_start, second_end);
    if (pos == NULL) return 0;
    int sz_sub_arr = (int)(second_end - second_start);
    for (int ix = 0; ix < sz_sub_arr; ix += 1)
        *pos++ = INT_MAX;  // set all elements to INT_MAX
    return sz_sub_arr;
}

int show_array(
    const int* vct, const int* past_end, const char* msg)
{
    if (msg != NULL) printf("%25s", msg);
    printf("    [");
    for (const int* p = vct; p != past_end; p += 1)
        printf("  %d", *p);
    printf("  ]\n");
    return 0;
}
```

#### Output

```
Using 1st provided set
              Base array:    [  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  0  1  2  3  4  5  -1  ]
               Sub_array:    [  2  3  4  5  ]
         Resulting array:    [  1  2147483647  2147483647  2147483647  2147483647  6  7  0  1  2  3  4  5  -1  ]

Using 2nd provided set
              Base array:    [  1  1  2  3  5  6  1  2  4  10  ]
               Sub_array:    [  1  2  3  ]
         Resulting array:    [  1  2147483647  2147483647  2147483647  5  6  1  2  4  10  ]
```

Comment: this is too much long, could you edit it only for two arrays that I can set and print manually without helping functions?

Comment: This code shows how to use function pointers and how to use a vector of test cases as the code is written. Also shows how to use a state machine, includes some discussion and the test output. It is more aligned with what I would expect from Stack Overflow.

Comment: Anyway I added a **TL:DR** section at the end with a shorter example

Comment: Side comment: the definition of ‘remove’ per OP is to shift the elements after the match into the area that held the sub array in the original array. The implemented solution simply fill that area with  INTMAX, Not meeting required functionality.

Answer (score 1):

There is a little mistake in your algorithm, It only compares the first item of the subarray to the array and if it matches it assumes that this is the starting of the subarray without seeing the following items.

**header files**

```
#include <stdio.h>
```

**function to remove sub array**

```c
int remove_sub(int *arr_start, int *arr_end, int *sub_start, int *sub_end)
{
    const int arr_len = arr_end - arr_start;
    const int sub_len = sub_end - sub_start;

    if (sub_len > arr_len)
        return 0;

    int *a_ptr = arr_start;
    int *s_ptr = sub_start;

    while (a_ptr != arr_end)
    {
        int count = 0;
        int *ptr = a_ptr;
        while (*ptr == *s_ptr && s_ptr != sub_end && ptr != arr_end)
        {
            ptr++;
            s_ptr++;
            count++;
        }
        if (count == sub_len)
        {
            int *start = a_ptr;
            int *end = arr_end;
            int *temp = a_ptr;

            for (int i = 0; i < sub_len; i++)
            {
                while (start != end)
                {
                    *a_ptr = *(++start);
                    a_ptr++;
                }
                a_ptr = temp;
                start = a_ptr;
                end--;
                arr_end--;
            }
        }
        s_ptr = sub_start;
        a_ptr++;
    }

    int *ptr = arr_start;
    while (ptr != arr_end)
    {
        printf("%d ", *ptr);
        ptr++;
    }

    return arr_end - arr_start;
}
```

**main function**

```c
int main()
{
    int arr[] = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, -1};
    int sub[] = {2, 3, 4, 5};

    int size_arr = sizeof(arr) / sizeof(arr[0]);
    int size_sub = sizeof(sub) / sizeof(sub[0]);

    int size = remove_sub(arr, arr + size_arr, sub, sub + size_sub);
    printf("size: %d\n", size);

    return 0;
}
```

***Note:** Pointer Arithmetic also counts `*(arr + i)`*

Comment: this `*(arr + i)` is forbidden by the task setting. This must be solved using pointer arithmetic. Here's the official note: Note: Be sure to use pointer arithmetic when solving the task! Trivial simulation of indexing with form expressions * (arr + i) is not allowed either

Comment: @codproe checkout the edited solution and let me know if it helped

Comment: first of all, you cannot change function declaration, so remove_subarray must accept only 4 parameters, which are `int * first_start, int * first_end,const int * second_start,const int * second_end)` you can change names, but int stays int, and const int stays const int... secondly this doesn't work for multiple subarrays, try this `{1,1,2,3,5,6,1,2,3,10}` and `{1,2,3}`, and thirdly you used auxiliary array, the point of this is to use two arrays that function accepts and using them remove subarray from array

Comment: `use while loop for the outer array to move the cursor (eg p). Within this loop, move the cursor through the second (inner) array with the cursor (e.g. q), until q has reached q2 (end) and until it is the same as 'p'. If ‘q’ has come to an end, it means that the array is in the second array. In this case, place the pointers in the position where the end of the inner array is, and move backwards, ejecting element by element (ejection is moving the elements to the left). Otherwise (if there is no subarray for the current element), 'reset' 'p' and 'q' should start from the next element.`

Comment: `* (arr + i) is not allowed either` this is funny: This is pointer arithmetic... All is pointer arithmetic in arrays after all, but taking `arr` that is `int*`, a pointer, and adding to it you do an arithmetic operation. Then we read **use the `*` operator to access the value. * (arr + i) is not allowed either**. What is a non trivial way?

Comment: @codproe  now check, no auxiliary array, function only accepting 4 parameters. _Also let me know if it works_

Comment: thank you very much, I found a way to solve this, btw your code doesn't work for these two arrays  int `{1,1,2,3,2,1,2,3,3,1,2,3}` and `{3}`

Answer (score 0):

You might want to take advantage of memory function (memcmp, memcpy), which can speed up the code, and create more elegant solution. I'm not sure if "using pointer arithmetic" implied that arr_start[i] is not allowed. If this is the case, then every reference to X[i] should be replaced with *(X+i), effectively replacing indexing with the equivalent pointer arithmetic.

```
int remove_sub(int *arr_start, int *arr_end, int *sub_start, int *sub_end)
{
    const int arr_len = arr_end - arr_start;
    const int sub_len = sub_end - sub_start;

    if (sub_len < 1 || sub_len > arr_len)
        return 0;

    // Search in arr position 0 .. (arr_len - sub_len)
    for (int i=0 ; i<arr_len-sub_len ; i++ ) {
        int *curr_arr = arr_start + i ;

        // Move to next element, if match not found
        if ( memcmp(curr_arr, sub_start, sub_len*sizeof(*sub_start) )
            continue ;

        // Match found: remove it and return
        int arr_tail = arr_len - i - sub_len ;
        memmove(curr_arr, curr_arr+sub_len, arr_tail*sizeof(*arr_start)) ;
        return sub_len ;
     }
     // No match found at all, return 0, no change to array.
     return 0 ;
} ;
```

Disclaimer: I did not compile/test. Possible that there are typos.